# Autosave of programmatically created NSTableColumn in NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults, nstableview, autosave, nstablecolumn

I have an `NSTableView` created in Interface Builder with some columns. I've set the tableview to autosave its settings (I set the autosave name in the Attributes Inspector and checked *Column information*). Now I want to add some other columns programmatically, but when I quit the app and relaunch it, these newly added columns disappear and the ones created in Interface Builder reappear.
Googling I found a work-around: changing the width of the added column gets the job done, but there must be a better solution!

EDIT: changing the column width only works *sometimes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to load the autosave data at the applications/NSTableView load?

Comment: Yes, you're right. After each launch I have first to add all columns programmatically and then use `[tableView setAutosaveName:filename]` and `[tableView setAutosaveTableColumns:YES]` to hide/show them as they were before quitting.

Answer (score -1):

the position, size and ishidden of a NSTableColumn is autosaved -- using the InterfaceBuilder autosave method. make sure to hit the 'Column Information' checkbox...